# Linux: Makefile: fatal error: opening dependency file

Tags: linux, makefile

Q-1. What is the difference between the below compilation errors in using Makefiles?

> fatal error: opening dependency file : Input/output error
>
> fatal error: opening dependency file : Permission denied
>
> fatal error: opening dependency file : No such file or
>   directory

Q-2. How do we correct each of them?

Comment: Please add some context. There isn't a definitive answer to this question.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @larks/ sounds like a homework question but important thing is "learning something". I will write answers but read them carefully and Google it next time.

For understanding the error types, you should read the error code. Differences of error types are quite clear.

**Input/Output errors** during filesystem access attempts mostly mean hardware issues. But sometimes missing libraries can cause this error type as well.

**Permission denied** is error type that you do not have permission to write related file or directory. That means you should add the permission to your current user or access root permissions.

**No such file or directory** is self descripted. This program tries to write or read a file that doesn't exist. For solving this problem you should check your env options or create manually (not recommended way).